# Javascript : Save JSON data to firebase database

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an object with JSON like string which is returned by a function tableToJson(). This is what it looks like.

```
{
{"Item Code":"sthing","Product Name":"sthing","Qantity":"1","Unit Price":"0","Item Total":"0"},
{"Item Code":"sthing","Product Name":"sthing","Qantity":"1","Unit Price":"0","Item Total":"0"},
{"Item Code":"sthing","Product Name":"sthing","Qantity":"1","Unit Price":"0","Item Total":"0"},
{"Item Code":"sthing","Product Name":"sthing","Qantity":"1","Unit Price":"0","Item Total":"0"}
}
```

How to save this on firebase database.
I am already saving some data above it with JS looks like this:

```
var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref('Bills');
function submitData(e){
e.preventDefault();
//variables for getting all values 
var receiptDate = document.getElementById('date').innerHTML;
var receiptTime = document.getElementById('time').innerHTML;
var receiptBillNo = getInputValues('billNo');
var receiptCompName = getInputValues('companyName');
var receiptEmail = getInputValues('email');
var receiptPhone = getInputValues('phone');
var discount = getInputValues('Discount');
var total = getInputValues('sumTotal');

var newDataref = databaseRef.push();
var itemsJson = tableToJson();//THIS WILL RETURN THE ABOVE JSON STRING
//itemsJson = tableToJson();
//JSON.parse(itemsJson);

newDataref.set({

    date: receiptDate,
    time: receiptTime,
    billNo: receiptBillNo,
    company: receiptCompName,
    email: receiptEmail,
    phone: receiptPhone,
    discount: discount,
    total:total,
    zitems: itemsJson

});
}
```

[image: why it is saving as string.]

Have look at my tableToJson()

```
function tableToJson(){
    var tableId = document.getElementById('dataEntryTable');
    var headName; 
    var headers = [];
    var dataArray = [];
    var rowCount = tableId.rows.length;
    var colCount = tableId.rows[0].cells.length;

    dataArray.push("[");
    for(var i = 1; i < colCount; i++){
        headName = tableId.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        headers.push(headName);
    }
    console.log(headers);
    for(var i = 1; i < rowCount; i++){
        dataArray.push("\n{");
        //FOR FIRST APPROACH:dataArray.push("\n/"" + i + "/" :{");
        for(var j = 1; j < colCount; j++){
            var currValue = tableId.rows[i].cells[j].childNodes[0].value;
            dataArray.push("\"" + headers[j-1] + "\":" + "\"" + currValue + 
            "\"");
            if(j < (colCount - 1)){
                dataArray.push(",");
            }
        }
        if( i < (rowCount - 1)){
            dataArray.push("},");
        }
        else{
            dataArray.push("}/n");
        }
    }
    dataArray.push("]");
    return dataArray.join("");
}
```

Is something wrong with this code.
Even if I parse it to JSON it is sending as string.

Comment: Cause you convert it to a String???! Or what should `THIS WILL RETURN THE ABOVE JSON STRING` mean?

Comment: It will taking input values from  a table and converting it to the JSON like string mentioned above

Comment: So why are you confused that it is a string when you say *it is a Json string* ... ?

Comment: I said JSON like, sorry if its confusing you.

Comment: I want to save all those values as an object not as string. Like its saving other values above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May convert the JSON string back to a js object:

```
newDataref.set({
  date: receiptDate,
  /*...*/
  zitems: JSON.parse(itemsJson)
});
```

But it would be definetly better to not stringify it at all.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems:

1. your `tableToJson` function returns a string, which you can solve by either making it return an actual JSON object, or by calling `JSON.parse` as Jonas answered.
2. Unfortunately the `JSON.parse()` will currently fail, due to the fact that your string is not valid JSON. You cannot nest objects in the way you've done. You'll either need to give each nested object a label:

   ```
   {
     "one": {"Item Code":"sthing","Product Name":"sthing","Qantity":"1","Unit Price":"0","Item Total":"0"},
     "two": {"Item Code":"sthing","Product Name":"sthing","Qantity":"1","Unit Price":"0","Item Total":"0"},
     "three": {"Item Code":"sthing","Product Name":"sthing","Qantity":"1","Unit Price":"0","Item Total":"0"},
     "four": {"Item Code":"sthing","Product Name":"sthing","Qantity":"1","Unit Price":"0","Item Total":"0"}
   }
   ```

   Or return an array instead of an object:

   ```
   [
     {"Item Code":"sthing","Product Name":"sthing","Qantity":"1","Unit Price":"0","Item Total":"0"},
     {"Item Code":"sthing","Product Name":"sthing","Qantity":"1","Unit Price":"0","Item Total":"0"},
     {"Item Code":"sthing","Product Name":"sthing","Qantity":"1","Unit Price":"0","Item Total":"0"},
     {"Item Code":"sthing","Product Name":"sthing","Qantity":"1","Unit Price":"0","Item Total":"0"}
   ]
   ```

If you go with the latter approach, take a moment to read [Firebase's blog post on using arrays](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried the both approach,for first : gave every nested object a label and second : returned an array instead of an object, again it is sending data as a string.

Comment: That means that your `tableToJson` is still returning a string and you're not converting it to JSON. Update your question with the latest code (including a **minimal** version of `tableToJson` that still reproduces the problem).

Comment: As expected your `tableToJson` returns a string, which means you'll need to call `JSON.parse` on its results before passing them to Firebase to turn it into a property JSON object.

Comment: I did sir, like I said I tried the first approach then I went for the array approach. Updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Neither of the two lines you commented will work. `JSON.parse` doesn't modify its argument, but *returns* the JSON object that it parses. So you need to *use the return value*. As Jonas showed do:    `zitems: JSON.parse(itemsJson)`

Comment: Thank you sir. Thank you for your time. That was real stupid mistake.